# Convergence rate when solving L1 regularized optimization via coordinate descent with tiny step?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, regularization

Wondering if there is an established result for the convergence rate when solving L1 regularized optimization via coordinate descent with tiny step? By "tiny step" I mean the step is always set to a very small positive constant, involving none of those step selection technique.

Answer (score 1):

A weak result derived from Boyd & Vandenberge "Convex Optimization" p. 479 is that for $l_1$-steepest descent (coordinate descent), with a step size of $t=\frac{1}{M}$ we have that 
$$
f(x^{(k)}) - p^* \leq c^k(f(x^{(0)})-p^*)\\
c = \left(1-\frac{m}{Mn}\right) < 1
$$
where the Hessian of $f$ is bounded by $MI\succeq \nabla^2 f(x) \succeq mI$. I would advise looking at that section to see if you can get something better.

EDIT: This doesn't 100% answer the original question, my apologies. However, $l_1$-regularized programs can be recast as SOCPs. Some techniques for optimization are listed on p599 and p601 of the above reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I check the textbook but I don't quite why the $\ell$-1 norm of gradient there is equivalent to the L-1 regularization for the target function to be minimized as in my question?

Comment: Basically, that section in the book just converts any norm to the 2-norm using the bounds established by equivalence of norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Properties.

Comment: Ah, I think I misread your original question!